# Unable to install Ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation

I bought a new Toshiba with Windows 10 installed.  I downloaded  “Ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386”
on a different Ubuntu computer and put it on a disk. The disk did install on the new computer. After the install finished it said remove disk and restart. 
After restart all it said was    >>Start PXE over IPv6. Press [ESC] to exit.

I have installed Ubuntu several times in the past on different computers, never saw this before. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you taken out the installable media? Is your BIOS pointed to boot from disk on which you installed grub?

Answer (score 2):

I never had this error but looking on the net it seems a problem of the boot sequence, maybe you have to change this on your BIOS (look if your first option it is a net boot sequence). As I look, it seems that your problems comes because he is trying to boot a SO from the net and it doesn't find it so you should change this option on the BIOS.

Try to put, in your boot option, the different options like this:

- CDROM
- USB
- HD
- NET

or try to disable the net option (if it is possible).

I expect it solves your problem. Good luck and let me know if it works! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to format your laptop and reinstall Ubuntu, it might have been an installation error if you did it before but it just didn't work this time.

Comment: That's not the right way to fix this issue. It is related to BIOS settings for boot device.

Comment: Ok, sorry didn't know

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps to create your installation media :

1.Download the .iso file from Ubuntu website.
2.Download a software named Universal USB installer.
3.Run it to create a bootable USB drive(preferrable), because if something goes wrong, you can recreate it.
4.Use the bootable USB drive to test drive Ubuntu or install it.

On power on , you will see, some option named **Boot Device** with some function key associated with  it. Enter that menu and select your USB stick as the boot device.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in some BIOS, that allows booting from network. That's what PXE is. You should check your BIOS to see if it's enabled and if it is, disable it. It should be something like "LAN boot ROM"